# How do I migrate a Northwind DB to Cassandra?

Tags: migration, nosql, cassandra

I want to migrate data from a Northwind database to Apache Cassandra.

How would I go about modelling the data for NoSQL? What are the recommended techniques and/or methodologies to accomplish this?

I have been looking online, but without any success yet.

Comment: This question belongs in DBA.SE and should not be closed. The topic of data modelling and DB administration are the right fit for the site as stated in https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. It is an appropriate question that is not listed in https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Answer (score 2):

Migrating data from a relational database to Cassandra isn't very straightforward since it requires data modelling to redesign the tables to fit your application's needs.

For most cases, the main motivation for migrating to Cassandra is the ability to scale. Cassandra is able to provide internet scale with millions of requests per second served concurrently.

In RDBMS, tables are normalised to avoid duplication with foreign keys used to join tables. It is the complete opposite in Cassandra -- tables are denormalised so they are optimised for very, very fast reads.

To demonstrate, consider a use case where you have customers, products and orders. In a relational DB, it is normal to store data about these entities in separate tables.

In Cassandra, we model the data based on the application queries. For example, if we have an application query like "get shipping address for customer email X", we need to design a table that is partitioned by email address:

```
CREATE TABLE customers_by_email (
    email text,
    shipping_address text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
)
```

To query this table:

```
SELECT shipping_address
    FROM customers_by_email
    WHERE email = ?
```

If we have an app query "get orders of customer id Y", we would design a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE orders_by_customerid (
    customer_id text,
    order_id text,
    order_date date,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id, order_id)
)
```

This CQL query would retrieve ALL the orders of a specific customer:

```
SELECT *
    FROM orders_by_customerid
    WHERE customer_id = ?
```

To retrieve a customer's specific order:

```
SELECT *
    FROM orders_by_customerid
    WHERE customer_id = ?
    AND order_id = ?
```

What I am trying to illustrate here is that the very first thing you need to do is list all the possible queries your application needs. Then you need to design a table for each of those queries. [Cassandra Data Modelling](https://www.datastax.com/dev/modeling) at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) has free tutorials and resources where you can quickly learn the concepts and methodology.

Once you're done with the data modelling, export the data out of your Northwind database into CSV files then do the transformation so that you end up with one CSV file for each CQL table.

You can then bulk-load those CSV files to Cassandra using the **[DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html)** (DSBulk) tool. DSBulk allows you to bulk load data in CSV or JSON format to a Cassandra table. You can also use DSBulk to export data from Cassandra to CSV or JSON.

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)

Cheers!